# How to override a phtml file from a custom module in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, overrides, frontend, phtml

I need to override

**/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml**.

For this, in **app/code/namespace/Customtab/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">namespace_Customtab::product/view/gallery.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
     </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

paste the custom phtml file in

**app/code/namespace/Customtab/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml**.

But it didn't works.Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Customtab::product/view/gallery.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: It works fine :)

Comment: when i add the above code the template gets overrided. but when you open configurable product and if you change the swatch it throws js error.

Answer (score 1):

Customizing the core Magento 2 functionality is a bad coding practice. The solution is to override a phtml file using a custom module in Magento 2.

Learn the implementation of both the methods at [Reference for override phtml](https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-phtml-file-using-custom-module-in-magento-2/)

Comment: Please check the link if its available before posting

Comment: @Tanmay link work

Comment: It did not work  previously may be site issuess

Comment: yes may be possible

Comment: Don't link of SE, just give an actual answer

Comment: @Dom  link of blog may help to new learners and i have posted when i was beginner
and also they can replay of blog comments that why i posted

Comment: Ignore this answer. Link demonstrates a lack of attention to detail and probably insufficient grasp of what the code is doing as there's no attempt at explanation.